# Does iCloud use windows Azure?

Tags: apple, azure

I just read this article on iCloud's use of Azure: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/is-apple-really-using-windows-azure-to-power-icloud/9687

Anyone know if there is any truth in it?

Comment: Given that neither Microsoft nor Apple are coming forward and confirming this, there's no way that this can be confirmed with certainty.  The article suggests that they're using the CDN parts of the Azure network, in addition to Amazon's services.  Sharing the load between multiple providers does make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a corroborating article on CultOfMac.com:

http://www.cultofmac.com/icloud-is-built-on-the-backs-of-windows-azure-and-amazon/100594

It looks like they are both citing InfiniteApple.net as a source.